# pandoc: New: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: latex, github-actions, pandoc

I am trying to translate a document from .md format to .pdf format with pandoc in github-actions CI (using `docker://pandoc/latex:2.14.1`).

```yaml
- uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.14.1
  with:
    args: --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont='Times New Roman' report.md -o report.pdf
```

and I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name pandoclatex2141_eb4592 --label c9e036 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_ARGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/lab-template/lab-template":"/github/workspace" pandoc/latex:2.14.1 --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont='Times New Roman' report.md -o report.pdf
pandoc: New: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

But, if I do not specify `-V mainfont='Times New Roman'`, then everything works fine...

Comment: Try: [Metadata syntax for GitHub Actions (github.com)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions)